# Probability of a coin expresses in a "strange" way

Tags: probability, statistics

In a book , the probability of head in a coin it's expressed as:

$P=\frac{\left \langle N_{H} \right \rangle}{N}=0.5$

I thought that the probability of head was : $P=\frac{N_{H}}{N}$

What is the meaning of these "right angle parenthesis" ?

Comment: Angular brackets are used to indicate the average of some quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have $N$ random variables $X_1,..,X_N$, where $X_i = 1$ if the coin is head and $0$ if it is tails.
Then the number of heads out of $N$ coin tosses is 
$$
N_H = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i
$$
and is a random quantity, since each $X_i$ is random. 
A different trial of $N$ coin tosses will give a different value for $N_H$.

The average number of heads is sometimes denotes by $\langle N_H \rangle$ is given by
$$
\langle N_H \rangle = \mathbb{E} [N_H] = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{E}[X_i]
$$
If the probability of getting heads for each coin toss is $P$, then 
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_i] = P \cdot 1 + (1-P) \cdot 0 = P
$$
and thus 
$$
\frac{\langle N_H \rangle}{N} = P
$$
which is different from
$$
\frac{N_H}{N} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i
$$
which is a random.

Comment: In pratice we use $\frac{\left \langle N_{H} \right \rangle}{N}=P$ cause $\frac{N_{H}}{N}=P$ it's probably not accurate (since it's referred to a single experiment) ?